# Different value when deployed in app.powerbi and in Power bi desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I need a measure/column in my cube (.bim file) to display the ‘**latest refresh date**’ of the cube...

To achieve this, I have a calculated column with code   **=NOW()**
[image]

My problem is that when I consume it from .pbix the date shows up in one language and when deployed to service app.powerbi.com it changes name….

pbix:
[image]

When deployed in app.powerbi:
[image]

I need to make sure that if I open the pbix and if I deploy in app.powerbi I see the same… How can I prevent this?

(Ideally I would like to see both in English).

Formatting doesn't seem to work, not sure why:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/supported-languages-countries-regions#choose-the-language-or-locale-of-power-bi-desktop

Answer (score 1):

```
VAR MonthName = 
        SWITCH(
            Month(NOW())
            ,7,"JULY"
        )
RETURN 
    DAY(NOW())  & " " & MonthName  & " " &  YEAR(NOW())
```

Comment: It doesnt work, I have updated the post.

Comment: Please, try it pbix

Comment: No, I can't I have a live model from SSAS cube, and we do all code in the ssas cube.

Comment: and it 's not allowed to save the function as it is, with error?

Comment: correct, it doesnt allow me, you can see the error message it says FORMAT only has 2 arguments, not 3.

Comment: I alterd my answer. Can this work?